# Como usar a flag "php_admin_value" no virtualhost através do PHP-FPM num Virtual Host específico?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, php-fpm

Eu decidi trocar o Apache2Handler pelo PHP-FPM no meu servidor. Após essa alteração, eu tentei rodar `sudo apache2ctl configtest` e recebi o seguinte erro:

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 53 of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:
>   Invalid command 'php_admin_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
>   Action 'configtest' failed.
>   The Apache error log may have more information.

Eu sei que é possível fazer essa adaptação através do arquivo `www.conf` do PHP FPM, porém a questão é que eu preciso que isso funciona para um virtualhost específico, e não para todos.

Exemplo:

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/projeto_x.conf

<Directory /home/servidor/projeto_x>
    php_admin_value open_basedir /home/servidor/projeto_x
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Como é que posso fazer essa configuração através do PHP FPM para um VHost específico?

Answer (score 1):

OBS: Não sei se eu entendi direito, talvez isso de certo, se não der comente para eu apagar a resposta errada, ou se der pra eu apagar essa linha.

1 - Crie um grupo e um usuário pra esse host (vão servir pra identificar qual site/sistema recebe esse host)

Usei 'teste' como exemplo.

2 - Crie um arquivo conf exlusivo pra esse site/projeto

```
sudo vim /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/teste.conf
```

E nesse arquivo:

```
[teste]
user = teste
group = teste
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-teste.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = comando1,comando2
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
```

3 - Restarta o php-fpm

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

4 - A esta altura ja deve estar rodando um processo 'teste', use o comando a baixo para averiguar:

```
ps aux |grep teste
```

Comment: Creio que sua resposta estaja correta, já que no FPM o PHP não roda junto ao Apache, mas roda via "comunicação", logo não tem como configurar o "phpflags" diretamente via VirtualHosts, tem que configurar no FPM. Não testei sua resposta ainda, mas é bem provavel de ser o caminho correto para o FPM.

Comment: Eu acredito que esteja correto também, eu usei isso porque no mesmo sistema eu precisava travar e liberar o shell_exec, só dividi em dois 'hosts' que não são bem hosts, e desabilitei em um e no outro não, funcionou certinho.